# How to parse Apple's IAP receipt mal-formatted JSON?

Tags: python, json, in-app-purchase

I got the JSON [from apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/VerifyingStoreReceipts/VerifyingStoreReceipts.html) like this

```
{
    "original-purchase-date-pst" = "2012-06-28 02:46:02 America/Los_Angeles";
    "original-transaction-id" = "1000000051960431";
    "bvrs" = "1.0";
    "transaction-id" = "1000000051960431";
    "quantity" = "1";
    "original-purchase-date-ms" = "1340876762450";
    "product-id" = "com.x";
    "item-id" = "523404215";
    "bid" = "com.x";
    "purchase-date-ms" = "1340876762450";
    "purchase-date" = "2012-06-28 09:46:02 Etc/GMT";
    "purchase-date-pst" = "2012-06-28 02:46:02 America/Los_Angeles";
    "original-purchase-date" = "2012-06-28 09:46:02 Etc/GMT";
}
```

This is not the [JSON](http://www.json.org/) we know. In JSON it's clearly defined that

> Each name is followed by : (colon) and the name/value pairs are separated by , (comma).

How can I even parse it in python's json (or simplejson) module?

`json` only supports `separators` in `json.dumps()`, not in `json.loads()`, and in `simplejson/decoder.py`, the `def JSONObject()` has hard-coded delimiter of `:` and `,`.

What can I do? Write my own parser?

Comment: @TrinhHoangNhu Yet Apple claim it be (see the doc link I provided above). It even support nested syntax.

Comment: @est - I think you are trying to parse the wrong receipt. From the link you provided:

Note: On iOS, the contents and format of the store receipt is private and subject to change. Your application should not attempt to parse the receipt data directly. Use the mechanism described here to validate the receipt and retrieve the information stored inside it.

You have to post the receipt to Apple for verification, the answer you then get is in JSON format.

Comment: @StefanDeitmer, in theory you are correct, however it's always nice to check the receipt first before sending to Apple. There are obvious error you can check. e.g. duplicate Transaction IDs.

Comment: @est - I don't think that's a good idea. They are explicitly saying that the receipt is in a proprietary format, subject to change without notice. Check the validation receipt instead.

Comment: @StefanDeitmer You can't rely everything on documented ones only. Plus it's well established format seen everywhere used by Apple.

Comment: The format is a serialized property list. On IOS you can parse it using   [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData: data                                                                         options:NSPropertyListImmutable format:nil error:&error]; so I assume the format is not going to change. In many code samples the "purchase-info" section from the local receipt is parsed and the transaction-id found is compared against the transaction ID from the response received from  buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is indeed rather messed up. A quick fix would be to replace the offending separators with a regular expression:

```
line = re.compile(r'("[^"]*")\s*=\s*("[^"]*");')
result = line.sub(r'\1: \2,', result)
```

You'll also need to remove the last comma:

```
trailingcomma = re.compile(r',(\s*})')
result = trailingcomma.sub(r'\1', result)
```

With these operations the example loads as json:

```
>>> import json, re
>>> line = re.compile('("[^"]*")\s*=\s*("[^"]*");')
>>> result = '''\
... {
...     "original-purchase-date-pst" = "2012-06-28 02:46:02 America/Los_Angeles";
...     "original-transaction-id" = "1000000051960431";
...     "bvrs" = "1.0";
...     "transaction-id" = "1000000051960431";
...     "quantity" = "1";
...     "original-purchase-date-ms" = "1340876762450";
...     "product-id" = "com.x";
...     "item-id" = "523404215";
...     "bid" = "com.x";
...     "purchase-date-ms" = "1340876762450";
...     "purchase-date" = "2012-06-28 09:46:02 Etc/GMT";
...     "purchase-date-pst" = "2012-06-28 02:46:02 America/Los_Angeles";
...     "original-purchase-date" = "2012-06-28 09:46:02 Etc/GMT";
... }
... '''
>>> line = re.compile(r'("[^"]*")\s*=\s*("[^"]*");')
>>> trailingcomma = re.compile(r',(\s*})')
>>> corrected = trailingcomma.sub(r'\1', line.sub(r'\1: \2,', result))
>>> json.loads(corrected)
{u'product-id': u'com.x', u'purchase-date-pst': u'2012-06-28 02:46:02 America/Los_Angeles', u'transaction-id': u'1000000051960431', u'original-purchase-date-pst': u'2012-06-28 02:46:02 America/Los_Angeles', u'bid': u'com.x', u'purchase-date-ms': u'1340876762450', u'original-transaction-id': u'1000000051960431', u'bvrs': u'1.0', u'original-purchase-date-ms': u'1340876762450', u'purchase-date': u'2012-06-28 09:46:02 Etc/GMT', u'original-purchase-date': u'2012-06-28 09:46:02 Etc/GMT', u'item-id': u'523404215', u'quantity': u'1'}
```

It should handle nested mappings as well. This does assume there are no escaped `"` quotes in the values themselves though. If there are you'll need a parser anyway.

Comment: well, `"[^"]*"` will break things like `"this line says \"hi\""`

Comment: @est: yup, at which point you'll need a parser as the language is no longer regular.

Comment: nice use of  `.rpartition(',')`, but it doesn't deal with nested JSON objects with a trailing `,`

Comment: @est: Realized that too when I scanned the documentation again. Corrected with another regex.

Answer (score 3):

If you add the following to your HTTP request header to iTunes

```
{'Content-Type' : 'application/json'}
```

It will return a real JSON formatted response that will work with json.loads

Comment: No, the client got the receipt, not via http.

Comment: As of iOS 6, the client receives an encrypted blob.  You have to verify the receipt on the server by sending a request to https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt (or https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt).  If you add the request header from above, the receipt response will be properly formatted as JSON.

Comment: I need to parse the "encrypted" blob of the receipt *before* sending it to APPL servers. Tip: it's base64 and it's not "encrypted"

Answer (score 1):

I got this helper function working and it seems to work good enough for the moment. I am using it to convert incoming (unverified) receipts to JSON and extract the transaction-ID. After verification I compare the 2 transaction ID's to make sure they match:

```
    function PropertyArrayStringToArray($data)
    {
        $data = str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', $data); 
        $data = preg_replace('/\t/', '', $data);  
        $data = str_replace('" = "'  ,'":"',$data);
        $data = str_replace('"="'    ,'":"',$data);
        $data = str_replace('";'     ,'",',$data);
        $data = str_replace(',}'     ,'}',$data);
        return json_decode($data,true);
    }
```

Feel free to use it (at your own risk) and improve it.